# Updating a character variable based on most recent date and then counting records by group in SQL

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I am using SQLite3 for this following query.

I have a table called "products" that looks like this:

[image]

I have a table called "transactions" that looks like this:

[image]

I have a table called "segments" that looks like this. **Notice that the variable "active_flag" denotes whether the segment is active.**

[image]

My goal is to

1. **Update** each customer's active segment based on their transaction
2. Provide the number of customers in each updated segment.

Here is how to update the segment:

- Mark the segment as "NEW2" if the customer made first transaction on or after
  '2016-03-01'.
- Mark the segment as "INACTIVE" if the customer haven't made any
  transaction since '2016-03-01'.

I know that I need to first find the latest transaction date. I can do this:

```
select t.cust_id, t.trans_id, s.seg_name, s.active_flag, max(t.trans_dt) as latest_transaction_date
from transactions t 
JOIN segments s
on t.cust_id = s.cust_id
GROUP by t.cust_id;
```

At the end, when I have all of the customers with their update segments, I know that I can count the number of customers in each segment with a groupby. However, I'm struggling with the intermediate step.

The hard part for me is updating a column, which I have never done.

The output should look like this.

```
 seg_name    count_cust
    ONE-OFFS    11
    LOYAL       15
    NEW2        17
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to update the segment :

```
update segments 
set active_flag = case when first_transaction_date >= '2016-03-01' 
  then true 
  else false 
end 
from 
(
select cust_id , min(trans_dt) first_transaction_date 
from transaction 
group by cust_id
) tr
where segments.cust_id = tr.cust_id
```

to get the count of customers in each segment:

```
select seg_name
        , count(*) count_total
        , count(distinct cust_id)  count_distinct_customer
from segments
group by seg_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it doesn't work. There is a syntax error in the first line near the alias "s". I fixed the table name to "segments", but that didn't remove the error. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: The "::timestamp" caused problems, so I removed it. I think that the inequality still works, because the minimal date starts at midnight (00:00:00). Beyond this issue, how do you incorporate the "NEW2" value into the seg_name? I know that you have re-defined the active_flag, but the segment name needs to be updated, too.

Comment: 1) New2 needs a closing quotation mark. 2) Why are we concatenating seg_name with NEW2? My goal is to create a new value under seg_name called NEW2 if it meets that condition with 2016-03-01. 3) I corrected the name of the table to "transactions".

Comment: you wanna add a new record in segment table with "NEW2" name?

Comment: Yes - see the last row in the expected output at the end of my question. NEW2 is a new segment name.